# Maven – Always download sources and javadocs

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way I can configure maven to *always* download sources and javadocs? Specifying `-DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true` everytime (which usually goes along with running mvn compile twice because I forgot the first time) becomes rather tedious.

Comment: Is this for the eclipse plugin? You shouldn't have to run that very often anyway...

Comment: No, it is for the command line program.  I don't have to run it very often, but it would be great if I had to run it never!

Comment: What is the command line? This is when you do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` right?

Comment: @sjr, yes in order to download sources and javadocs one can execute `mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true`

Comment: I think this question still is **not** answered. The accepted answer is related to Eclipse plugin only. @AlexisGamarra's answer is the closest but does not solve the "persistence" of the solution - it does not set Maven to do it *always* whenever you run *mvn install*.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Open your settings.xml file `~/.m2/settings.xml`  (create it if it doesn't exist). Add a section with the properties added. Then make sure the activeProfiles includes the new profile.

```xml
<settings>

   <!-- ... other settings here ... -->

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>downloadSources</id>
            <properties>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Edit: As mentioned by Jingguo Yao, this works with Eclipse IDE only - the same can also be configured in your IDE of choice. In Elcipse via Window -> Preferences -> Maven menu, though this probably has to done at every workspace level and for fresh Eclipse installations.

Alternatively configure the maven-dependency-plugin in your pom.xml in a separate profile and run it as required - keeping it in the main build will lead to build times (needlessly elongating (not to mention space) at places like your build nodes that don't need either sources or java docs. Preferable this should configured in some org or division parent pom.xml, otherwise it has be repeated everywhere in different places

Comment: I'm trying these profile properties in Maven 2.2.1 and 3.0.2 and they don't work. The target repository is Archiva. Any suggestions on what  else can be tried? I've also tried using dependency:sources goal. Thanks

Comment: Moreover, in Eclipse you can just go to Preferences -> Maven (No subcategory). There, you can check "Download artifact Sources/JavaDocs". However, sometimes Eclipse doesn't want to create that file manually (happened to me in Luna). In that case - go there, paste this answer wrapped in settings tags and tell Eclipse to re-load it, and it should work.

Comment: This worked for me: in Eclipse go to Preferences -> Maven (No subcategory). Check 
 - "Download artifact Source"
 - "Download artifact JavaDocs"
 - "Update Maven projects on startup" (just because I can't find the manual way)
Then restart Eclipse. Done

Comment: In Eclipse, in the Maven depencies you can right-click the jar and you have access to a menu : download Sources, JavaDoc, ... So you can do it on a need basis.

Comment: This only effects Maven Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Eclipse Mars; right-click on a maven project, on menu go to 'Maven' -> 'Download JavaDoc'. Your project will get rebuilt. cheers

Comment: This should **not** be the accepted answer! As @JingguoYao stated, it only affects the Maven Eclipse plugin. The original question was not bound to Eclipse, but rather to the Maven itself.

Comment: Is it possible to do it at project level ?

Answer (score 221):

In my case the "settings.xml" solution didn't work so I use this command in order to download all the sources:

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

You also can use it with other maven commands, for example:

```
mvn clean install dependency:sources -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

To download all documentation, use the following command:

```
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Comment: I think this question still is **not** answered. The accepted answer is related to Eclipse plugin only. Your answer is the closest but does not solve the "persistence" of the solution - it does not set Maven to do it *always* whenever you run *mvn install*.

Answer (score 57):

Just consolidating and prepared the single command to address source and docs download...

```
mvn dependency:sources dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Answer (score 44):

Answer for people from Google

In **Eclipse** you can manually download **javadoc** and **sources**.

To do that, right click on the project and use

- Maven -> Download JavaDoc
- Maven -> Download Sources

Comment: And in IDEA you can right click the Module, and under the Maven menu, there's an option to download sources and/or documentation

Comment: @Betlista read first line of the post. Lots of people go from google to here looking for something else. But end up going in here, even with different keywords

Answer (score 16):

I am using Maven 3.3.3 and cannot get the default profile to work in a user or global `settings.xml` file.

As a workaround, you may also add an additional build plugin to your `pom.xml` file.

```
<properties>
    <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.10</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Download Java source JARs. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 10):

On **NetBeans** : 
open your project explorer->Dependencies->[*file.jar*] rightclick->Download Javadoc

Answer (score 4):

As @xecaps12 said, the simplest/efficient approach is to change your Maven settings file (~/.m2/settings.xml) but if it is a *default* settings for you, you can also set it like that

```
<profile>
  <id>downloadSources</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
      <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, you're just declaring unused global properties. I believe the mythical solution came from the `maven-eclipse-plugin`: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/attach-library-sources.html

Comment: Nope, its just a simplification of the "resolved" answer ;)

Comment: The "resolved" version doesn't work either. (I made the same comment there, too, but have removed it temporarily while I confer with you.) So - are you saying your answer (and thus the resolved answer) actually works for you?? I mean, 159 people uploaded that wrong-or-outdated answer, so clearly it works for someone. If it works as you say, then I'm doing something wrong, as are the several people on the resolved answer in its comments and I'd *love* to learn that and get that working.

Comment: I suppose those global var are checked by eclipse plugin when you are actually developing with eclise. the source fetching is done by eclipse and not by maven on command line.

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans, you can instruct Maven to check javadoc on every project open :

`Tools` | `Options` | `Java` icon | `Maven` tab | `Dependencies` category | `Check Javadoc` drop down set to `Every Project Open`.

Close and reopen Netbeans and you will see Maven download javadocs in the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on the answer from [kevinarpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257299/kevinarpe) this does both sources and Javadocs:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>sources</goal>
            <goal>resolve</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done per plugin. See [this chapter](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_configuring_maven_plugins.html) from the Maven book.

You might be able to configure the dependency plugin to download sources (even though I haven't tried it myself :-).

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify file `mvn` (or `mvn.cmd` if in windows) and add whatever command line switches you need (as mentioned by other answers).  If you don't want to modify the install files (which I'd recommend), create a `mymvn` (or `mymvn.cmd`) wrapper that invokes the regular `mvn` with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you should be able to do something by setting a default active profile in your settings.xml

See

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Ah! Just exactly as described by @xecaps12

Comment: You should really copy the relevant parts from the link into your answer, just in case the URL breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use KeyStore to Download the Jars. If you have any Certificate related issues you can use this approach:

```
mvn clean install dependency:sources -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="Path_To_Your_KeyStore"
```

If you want to know how to create KeyStores, this is a very good link:
[Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

For the sources on dependency level ( pom.xml) you can add :

```
<classifier>sources</classifier>
```

Answer (score 0):

For intellij users, inside the pom.xml file, right click anywhere and select Maven -> Download sources and Documentation.