# JSF + Hibernate web application development environment

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, ide, application-server

i want to learn JSF and soon Hibernate and I was wondering which IDE(Netbeans, Eclipse, Jboss Developer Studio, etc.) and which application server(EAP, Glassfish, etc.) people generally use for these frameworks. Ideally, i would want to have the libraries supported with java docs already.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a better question would be: "How can I set up Eclipse so that I can see the Javadocs of the libraries I am using?"

Comment: Yeah, but I was also wondering what other people use for these frameworks. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. It's just that these questions don't have a straightforward answer. So it is a good practice to try to narrow down the scope of a question. See the FAQ for [questions to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this post will likely be closed as it is not a real question and subject to opinions, I will none the less give my opinion for you.

I am learning Java EE myself using NetBeans and Glassfish using the [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html) and [Beginning Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022889X)

For application Server: JBoss has alot of hosting options around, I haven't found as many for the other app servers.

If you are looking for libraries already supported, both JBoss and Glassfish conform to the Java EE 6 spec. Glassfish is the reference implementation for EE6.

Jboss favors Eclipse and Maven (among others) while Glassfish favors NetBeans and ANT (among others).

With that being said, I will finish by saying that any choice is dependent upon your goals, as well as your familiarity with the tool chain.

Answer (score 2):

JSF + Hibernate should work fine with any application server, moreover they will also work with servlet containers(Tomcat, Jetty). You should also decide which build manager to use - Maven or Ant.

As I use maven + eclipse + Jetty, I will describe what I would do :

1. I've configured maven to [download sources and javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs). So after editing pom.xml when I run `mvn clean package` everything is in place
2. To make it work in eclipse(you need to have m2e plugin installed): Right-click on Package Exploer->Import->Existing Maven Projects->Your project
3. As for jetty, you can use [maven-jetty-plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) and run your project from command-line with mvn jetty:run or [from eclipse itself](http://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/setup-jettymaven-for-developing-web-applications-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse Enterprise, JSF 2.1.x with Primefaces and the choice of server is between Tomcat 7 (for simple webapps) and JBoss 7.1 (if I want to use EJB technology).

Currently I do use Eclipse Juno but I have some performance problems with it (which should for the most part be fixed in the pending service release 2 or so I have read).