# Where can I find spring3.1 aspect Java source code. Seem to be nowhere in github or anywhere else

Tags: spring, aspectj

Usually I learn new  `frameworks` by going through each line of  the source code

I have `spring 3.2` in my `eclipse` project but `java aspect classes` are not included. 
I tried to `decompile` them but they look messed up

Any where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your code a maven project, and it is setup well, it will download the sources automatically.  So I recommend you setup your project in maven.

Answer (score 0):

you can find here a good configuration of a spring 3.2 project with maven,

https://github.com/andonescu/springmvc-freemarker

and use maven to download source code, see this link to help you 
[Maven – Always download sources and javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs)