# How do I add javadocs for restlet using Maven?

Tags: maven, restlet-2.0

I've created a maven project using m2eclipse plugin, I'am able to import dependencies through the following code,

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>
<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>  
   <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>  
   <version>2.1.2</version>  
</dependency>
```

However, I want to **configure javadocs for the downloaded dependecies** so that I can check the documentation while working. How do I achieve the object?

Comment: Please see [Maven – Always download sources and javadocs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs) and [get source jars from maven repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository).

Comment: Charlee, It seems that m2eclipse plugin automatically downloads the source because when I checked the Maven depenedencies for the source path, I got this .m2/repository/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.1.2/org.restlet-2.1.2-sources.jar. However, initially I could not access the javadocs, therefore this post. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up your pom.xml, **right click on your project -> Maven -> Download JavaDoc**.