# Add All Missing Javadoc in Referenced Libraries

Tags: eclipse, maven, javadoc

I have imported, from git, a large build that has a bunch of 3rd party dependencies.  The annoying thing is, that there is no javadoc attached for any of the 3rd party apis!  Is there any way to automatically add javadoc to an Eclipse project's libraries (all referenced libraries, not just one)?  It would take way too long to add all the javadoc one by one.

Although I'm using gradle to build, it uses maven under the hood and generates a pom.  I would figure that there's a way to generate javadoc from all referenced libraries in the pom, rather than have to add them each one at a time via the eclipse build path.

My instinct says there's not simply by asking 'how would we know remotely where the javadoc is kept', but I have to ask just in case someone knows a way.  I'd hate to add all the javadoc manually and figure out there's a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this answer? [Maven – Always download sources and javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs)

If that doesn't work, then probably the sources are unavailable for the dependencies you added (and you'll have to do it manually, as far as I know).