# Maven can not resolve(download) properties that used in dependencies

Tags: java, maven-3

I am new in maven,I have very simple project that used intelij idea. my pom file is :

```
<groupId>Pilot</groupId>
<artifactId>Pilot</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
        <name>Jboss Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>snapshots.jboss.org</id>
        <name>Jboss Snapshots Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
                <id>jboss-releases-repository</id>
        <name>JBoss Releases Repository</name>
        <url>
            https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/
        </url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.jpa.version>4.2.6.Final</hibernate.jpa.version>
    <jdk.Version>1.7</jdk.Version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  End Hibernate dependencies -->

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END Spring 3 dependencies -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--java unit test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Oracle Driver-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

I do not why Intelij Idea do not download dependencies, my pom file does not have build  tagand plug in teg. what should I do?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is not error in console after instal, just write downloadint but it is not download any thing

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved after I changed repository urls.