# always download sources (and javadocs) from maven ant task

Tags: maven, ant

I am trying to get [this ant-based project's](https://github.com/typelevel/scala) `init` target to download all the sources and javadocs.

I added the following to my `~/.m2/settings.xml` (as per [Maven – Always download sources and javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs)) but it doesn't force source downloads when used from ant:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>downloadSources</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
      </properties>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
```

The only way I could get the sources to download was by hacking `build.xml` so that all `<artifact:dependencies>` elements include `sourcesFilesetId="sources.dependency.fileset"`, but this is a pretty distasteful commit that is unlikely to be accepted by the maintainers. A better solution would exist with a property file definition, preferably in the user's settings (not something that mutates the project definition)

Is there a simpler way to ensure that all the sources (and potentially javadocs) are globally downloaded in maven ant tasks?

Comment: Is there any reason why you  try to do that via ant-task instead of maven directly?

Comment: Because it's an ant project maybe?

Comment: But it might be better to use maven like `mvn dependency:source` see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html

Comment: This isn't a maven project. If you'd like to submit a PR to turn it into a maven project, I'm sure they'd welcome that. But since it's the build config for a compiler, with several bootstrapping phases, I can guarantee you that such a port won't be trivial.