# how to attach openCV docs into my project

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, javacv

How can I attach the openCV API docs to my project? Currently when I hover over a specific openCV method I do not see any docs, and I have to refer to the docs website every time I need get familiar with any method.

Note: I am using openCV 2.4.11 in eclipse

Comment: Have a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs). You can either download them via `mvn` command line or specify it as default in your maven config. (I assume it's a maven project)

Comment: @SubOptimal actually it is not a maven it is java project in eclipse

Comment: I had a closer look. Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Did you find the answer or not, I also have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

As there is [no offical Maven repository](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3097) for [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) and the project does not provide a `javadoc` JAR file. The only possible solution seems to be

1. download the source repository
2. build the javadoc JAR yourself (see: http://code.opencv.org/issues/1847)