# Eclipse|Maven: Can't download source code of jar package?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

There are plenty of similar questions in stackoverflow, like [Get source JARs from Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository), [Maven – Always download sources and javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs), etc.

Follow the instructions suggested by those answers, Eclipse still can't download source code of jar package, but `javadoc` has been downloaded.

Does someone can tell me why? I fell quite confused.

Comment: Esse erro já estar aberto aqui a bastante tempo, porém quero descrever a solução que fiz em meu projeto, Hoje dia 02/06/2020 Passei pelo mesmo erro resolvi apagando a pasta .m2 do maven no caminho C:\Users\NOME_DE_USUARIO_DO_SEU_COMPUTADOR    .m2     pronto eu apaguei essa pasta e execultei maven update force.

Comment: Could you please use English in your comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you are using an embedded version of maven.

There are two items you need to check:

1. Check if the options in Eclipse are selected as screen bellow

[image]

The second approach is to select an external installation of maven.

Take a look in the screenshot bellow. I'm using an external installation of maven.

[image]

In the second approach maven will read the settings.xml of external installation.

Comment: Thx for your time, after check the local repository, I find that the `xxx-source.jar` has been downloaded for the `xxx.jar`, but `xxx-source` just don't show up in the Eclipse, what can I do?

Comment: On open a .class file, click on "Attach Source" button. Then select the xxx-source jar file in maven repository.

Comment: I am behind a firewall. The above was not good enough. I had to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430107/3124333 first, and then Eclipse was able to pick the sources up with no problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are few ways you can do it

```
1. mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources
2. mvn dependency:sources
```

3. or below in pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
  <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
</properties>
```

Comment: Step 2 (`mvn dependency:sources`) was the one that helped. Changing Eclipse preferences or setting the properties in pom.xml had no influence in my environment.