# Download sources in Eclipse Neon with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I installed Eclipse Neon, which has m2e plugin already installed.

In `Window->Preferences->Maven->User Settings` I specified path to `C:\Users\Морф\.m2\settings.xml`. This file contains:

```
<profile>
    <id>downloadSources</id>
    <properties>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    </properties>
</profile>
.....
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

But sources are not downloaded automatically. I attempted Maven-> Download Sources, but still nothing.

My Eclipse Mars uses the same `settings.xml` file, and **all sources are automatically downloaded in Eclipse Mars**, so file is **correct**.
So, how can I download sources automatically via maven in Eclipse Neon?

Comment: Is your `downloadSources` profile active in the settings? See there http://stackoverflow.com/a/5782039/1743880

Comment: yes, it is active

Comment: The settings in your question does not show it.

Comment: I have edited question.

Comment: Can you post the output of `mvn help:all-profiles` to  help us confirm if the `downloadSources` profile is indeed being activated ? This can be done from the command line from the root of the maven project. The output of that command should list ALL profiles (i.e. active and inactive) in the form `Profile Id: SomeProfile (Active: true , Source: settings.xml)`

Comment: When do you pretend the sources to be downloaded automatically, and where? Do you want the `-sources.jar` to be downloaded together with the  `.jar` dependencies? In other words: How do you know that the sources were not downloaded?