# Downloading artifacts with all classifiers into a chosen directory

Tags: java, maven

We have a private repository at work so once a while we need to download artifacts from the central repository and upload them.

Someone wrote a program a while ago for that which didn't always work perfectly: it would download all dependencies for each artifact separately, it would first scan the dependency tree and only then download them, it wouldn't download sources and javadocs, was slow, etc.

Recently I have come across this useful maven plugin called [dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) and its goal [get](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html).

So now to download some artifact, let's say for instance `com.sparkjava.spark-core:2.5.4`, I would type on my terminal:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.4
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.4:sources
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.4:javadoc
```

Which would download the artifact along with all its dependencies to the directory `~/.m2/repository` which I can later transfer to our private repository.

This method works good but has 2 problems:

1. I have to run the command 3 times when each time the classifier is different and I would like to get all classifiers at once.
2. It always downloads the artifacts into `~/.m2/repository`, which can sometime contain other artifacts I'm not intrested in having on the private repository. I need be able to choose another directory destination.

What can I do about these issues? About the first one I can work it around with an alias (which will still run the same command 3 times) but I have no idea what to do about the second issue and it's not mentioned on the plugin's documentation either.

Comment: what is the requirement for (1) if you can elaborate

Comment: I would suggest to start using a repository manager like Artifactory, Nexus where you precheck the artifacts and afterwards you can offer them for internal use...

Comment: To set classifier to "all" to get all available classifiers. @nullpointer

Comment: updated from a post on SO in the answer

Answer (score 0):

To solve (2), you can update the `settings.xml` with a tag

```
<localRepository>C:\Users\my\custom\existing\directory</localRepository>
```

and make sure when you are building the project, the same `settings.xml` looked into which can be done using

```
mvn clean install -gs <pathToDirectory>
```

***Note***  - Please modify the path accordingly.

---

To solve (1), adding the following to `settings.xml` should work as well -

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>downloadSources</id>
        <properties>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

***Source*** - [Maven – Always download sources and javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs)

---

Other maven command that could help here is -

[resolve command with classifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html) :

```
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc #downloads all the documentation
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for a one command solution without involving settings.xml. I tried runnign mvn dependency:get -Dmaven.repo.local=dest -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true -Dartifact=com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.4 which worked for changing the destination but it did not download sources and javadocs. From googling they seem to be eclipse's plugin properties: http://maven.apache.org/components/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/attach-library-sources.html