# Can't download sources for some Maven project dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In my Maven project I can't download the sources for some dependencies. For example have a look at the first project in the below image. I noticed that the icon before the project name has a slightly different icon than the rest of the dependencies.

[image]

And if I click on the project and go to Maven, it does not give me the option of downloading the sources:

[image]

This is how it looks for other dependencies:

[image]

What am I missing here? How **do** I download the sources?

Comment: This appears to be a question about Eclipse. You'd get more help if you tagged it as such.

Comment: @bmargulies. Agreed. Done

Comment: Please check the same library has source included JAR in maven repo, that may be the reason its not showing the download source option

Comment: You are not missing anything. The first project has its sources downloaded previously and the second doesn't.

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, so how do I download them? That's the question.

Comment: If thats the question, it might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs

Comment: @nullpointer this is not the same as I don't have this problem with other dependencies. Only with this specific project. Moreover, I can't even manually force it to download the sources since the menu item is not available as I highlighted in my question.

Comment: I assume that it is not an bug of Maven or Eclipse, but the author of the JAR published the bytecode without source code and Javadoc (by mistake or for legal reasons).

Comment: The project you have marked is a SNAPSHOT version which means it is not from Maven Central so it must be something from inside your company and so it could be that the source has not been published...