# How to tell eclipse to read javadocs from maven repo?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javadoc

I have a maven project in eclipse and want eclipse to show me the docs of an item (class, member, interface...) when hovering over it with the mouse cursor. When I hover over an item the popup displays the following text:

> Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc
>   and hence no Javadoc could be found.

I know I can tell eclipse the location of the docs of each dependency myself, but I want eclipse to automatically search for docs and sources in my local maven repository itself.
The local repo is already entered at
window -> preferences -> Maven -> User Settings -> Local Repository (From merged user and global settings)

How can I configure eclipse to look for docs & sources in my local maven repo automatically?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project, and in the Maven menu, tell it to download the Javadoc.

Comment: Well, it downloaded the docs and sources, they are all present in the local repo, but eclipse does not show them.