# Maven Central Repository Artifact Source Code / Project URL / License Identification

Tags: maven, maven-central, maven-repository

I'm new to working with Java and have questions regarding the Maven Central Repository. I am much more familiar with Python and PyPI, so I will provide the equivalent in PyPI that I would like to find in Maven.

1. How can I find the source code for the artifacts in Maven Central? Typically, I see the JAR file and prefer not to decompile these files. Typically, PyPI packages have the source file type in the "Download files" tab.
2. How can I find the associated project URL to a maven artifact? In PyPI, the package page has a set of project links and generally provides a repository link (e.g., Github, Bitbucket)
3. How can I identify open-source projects in the Maven central repository? The license for PyPI projects is tagged directly in the meta-reference on the sidebar of a project page.

I appreciate any insight into these questions. Thanks!

Comment: You can configure maven to download the sources and javadocs. See this other question: [Maven – Always download sources and javadocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780758/maven-always-download-sources-and-javadocs) - Also you can configure your IDE (intellij or eclipse?) to download these, so you can naviagate to the code rather than decompiling the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When a distributor decides to provide them, you can find `-sources.jar` and a `-javadoc.jar` files in the artifacts folder. (common IDE's are aware of that&provide buttons/menus, "Maven>Download XXX";)

   - like [e.g. here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0-RC2/)
   - [Artifact javadoc](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.3/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html) (for the sophisticated ones, `javadoc` and `sources` refers to the (common) "classifier" of the artifact)
   - [how (easy) to produce them](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html)
2. In the pom:

   - [`project.url`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#more-project-information) tag provides:

     > The project's home page.
   - [`project.scm`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#scm) element provides (should provide!) "source control" related (multiple) urls (read-only, contributer, public-browsing).
   - besides that many other things(and sub-things) can have url in a [maven project/pom](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) (distributionManagement(i.e repository), organisation, developer,...).
3. [`project.licenses`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#licenses) element!

You can be sure to find all of these three (- four) in all (at least latest) artifacts in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/), due to:

Their [Publishing Requirements](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/)!;

Comment: thanks for the quick response and feedback. This really helps!

Comment: welcome (also to [SO] & to java/maven)! Thanks for clear and structured question! +1;)