# How to get a source reference URL of a jar file?

Tags: java, github, build, jar, ant

I am working on building a project and have some dependent jar files with me. But to put them in production, I first need to identify the sources of the jar, i.e. find out the source code online and get those URLs as references. I want to know how or where I can get the jar's online source URLs for legal purposes.

Please note: My main aim is not to get the source code of the jar, I can do that with de-compiler. I want to get the online source URL of the jar itself for legal purposes.

I have mostly just tried googling it as I am very new to this. I managed to get the download urls for the jar but I am not able to find the source urls.

Comment: Is it a [maven artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1895492/6309)?

Comment: Yes it can be considered as maven artifact. So basically I am trying to shift an application from maven to ant. So currently have the jars build in ant but I am ok with it being treated as maven build jar.

Comment: "I am trying to shift an application from maven to ant.": so you cannot use `mvn dependency:copy` as suggested in the answer I have linked?

Comment: Actually no, because I already have the artifacts, I want the source url of those artifacts so I can produce proof of correctness and get a license for those jars to be used commercially.

Comment: Sure but the source might also on Maven central, with a [`-source` classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70298511/6309).